# Positioning a css menu into the top right hand corner

Tags: html, css, menu, position, fixed

Im having difficulty moving the menu over/ fixing it to the top right hand corner. Any help would be really appreciated .

html and css code @ http://pastebin.com/qAcUqAU2

Comment: Please try to isolate the relevant HTML and CSS for your question, and add it to the question body. It's more likely that you get an answer that way. As it stands, your question risks being closed as "not a real question".

Comment: describe your exact issue in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

You can make some small changes as follows,

```
     ul#css3menu1 ul
     {
       left:57px;
     }
```

I think this might be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

1. first i think **float your div to the right**, and set your `margins 0 0 0 0 to zero`.
2. on your CSS you should create `position: absolute` to make it independent, and make it
   `z-index: 100` to make it stand on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, think this will help you.

create another id or class & give  `text-align:right;` property. Put your menu code in this div.